# image rotation in frequency domain

Tags: image, matlab, rotation, frequency

I found a code about image rotation in frequency domain. But I couldn't understand this code. This code works correct. Can anyone describe this code? Actually I have to write a code to rotate an image in frequency domain in polar coordinates. Do you think this code 
meet the requirements.

```
clear;
img=imread('cameraman.tif');
imshow(img); title('original image');
theta=26,5;
N=size(img,1);
M=size(img,2);                                      

fimg=fftshift(fft2(fftshift(img)));

p=ones(N,1)*[-N/2:(N-1)/2];               % horizontal axis
q=-p';                                                     % vertical axis

theta=2*pi*theta/360;
g=1/(N^2).*fimg;
z1=exp(i*pi/N.*((p.^2-q.^2)*cos(theta)-2*p.*q*sin(theta)));
z2=exp(-i*pi/N.*((p.^2-q.^2)*cos(theta)-2*p.*q*sin(theta)));
k=ifft2(fft2(g.*z1).*(fft2(z2)));
figure,
imshow(abs(fftshift(flipud(k))), [0 255]); 
title(['Cameraman rotated at ' num2str(theta*360/(2*pi))  ' Degrees']); axis off
```

Comment: and what don't you understand about it ?

Comment: I didn't understand z1, z2 and k. How we can rotate the image with z1, z2 also I didn't understand p and q actually I didn' understand the logic of the code. Did you understand second part of my question actually I have to write a code to rotate an image in frequency domain in polar coordinates. Can you help me.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://www.clear.rice.edu/elec301/Projects01/image_filt/properties.html).

For the rotation, there is no properties. But this code using the shift properties to apply the rotation.

In z1, you have the coordinate `(p,q)` compute normaly as well, but just by applying the 2D rotation matrix to your coordinate, you can use the shift properties.

And notice, this code change a the sign every where, that why there no minus in z1 instead of z2.

```
Rotation : [cos(theta) -sin(theta);
            sin(theta) cos(theta)];
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know rotation in frequency code with using Rotation : [cos(theta) -sin(theta); sin(theta) cos(theta)];. In polar coordinates.

Comment: Also I didn't understand your answer can you explain a little more.